# add spark binding for Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, spark-view-engine

In our MVC3 project, we are using the Spark view engine. We have set up a Bindings.xml file that has several bindings including one for Html.BeginForm , as shown below:

```
<element name="Form">
    <start># using (Html.BeginForm("@action", "@controller", new RouteValueDictionary{{"@route-*"}}, FormMethod.@method, new Dictionary[[string,object]]{{"@*"}})) {</start>
    <end># }</end>
</element>
```

We use this in our views as follows:

```
<Form controller="Account" action="Create" method="Post">
....
</Form>
```

We now have several cases where we would like to use ajax forms and so, ideally, we would like to add a new binding so that we could use

The issue is that Ajax.BeginForm accepts an AjaxOptions object. This object is used to configure things like the UpdateTargetId, the method and callbacks for success/failure.

In Razor, I would normally call something like:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Account", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "mydiv" }) )
```

Depending on the use case, we will want to configure different fields on the AjaxOptions object and ignore the others.

Is there any way that we could add a spark binding for ajax forms that would allow us this functionality? eg: so that we could declare ajax forms something like:

```
<AjaxForm controller="Account" action="Create" ajax-UpdateTargetId="mydiv"></AjaxForm>
```

or in another instance

```
<AjaxForm controller="Account" action="Create" ajax-OnComplete="handleSuccess"></AjaxForm>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the binding:

```
<element name="AjaxForm">
    <start># using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions{"@ajax-*"})) {</start>
    <end># }</end>
</element>
```

And to use it in your code:

```
<AjaxForm ajax-UpdateTargetId="mydiv">
    Some form elements go here...
</AjaxForm>
```

Add your own overloads as required for the Controller / Action params.

The only caveat with this is that the options you can set using the @* wildcard initializer must be of type string.

Comment: thanks, that seems to work. The problem I was having was that I was using double curly braces eg new AjaxOptions{{"@ajax-*"}}

Comment: yeah if you're initialising a dictionary you need the doubles, but this is just a standard object initialiser

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you've tried this and it hasn't worked for you?

```
<element name="AjaxForm">
    <start># using(Ajax.BeginForm(@action, @controller, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = @ajax-UpdateTargetId }) ) {</start>
    <end># }</end>
</element>
```

And then for different use cases - you just add overloads of the above ordered from *most specific to least specific* and the Bindings will just pick the right one base on your attributes supplied.

Let me know on a comment to this answer, and if it hasn't worked, then I'll throw a quick example together and get it to compile and I can give you a guaranteed solution to it - this is all just off the top of my head.

I don't recall this being a little tricky when I tried before, except for the `AntiForgeryToken` part, but I tend not to use the Ajax helpers any more in favour of JSON calls using jQuery. But there's no reason you can't use this as a Binding if you wish.

Let me know...
Rob G

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would work, but I think what Fatal was getting at was if you could AjaxOptions {new {{"@ajax-*"}}}

Comment: Doesn't need to be a dictionary... from what I can tell, Spark just iterates over the elements in a wildcard pattern and spits them out in propertyname="value" fashion which will work perfectly fine for setting string based elements on an object initialiser. Just posted a sample

Comment: True - I guess I meant they had to be strings